# Using LoaderManager without SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to update an app I wrote a year or so ago and upgrade all calls to deprecated code. In one place, I was using a SimpleCursorAdapter in a ListView, and I'd like to replace that with a proper LoaderManager, for several reasons.

The problem is, that all the examples I've been able to find of using a LoaderManager actually still use SimpleCursorAdapter, even though it's deprecated. This includes the official documentation. Can anyone point me to the correct way to do this? I'm willing to update my ListActivity to a ListFragment if needed, and do whatever else is required. I just can't figure out how to use LoaderManager without falling back on deprecated classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is, that all the examples I've been able to find of using
>   a LoaderManager actually still use SimpleCursorAdapter, even though
>   it's deprecated.

The `SimpleCursorAdapter` class isn't deprecated and was even introduced in the compatibility package. What is deprecated and is giving you a warning is its [one of its constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) which does the queries on the main UI thread.

> Can anyone point me to the correct way to do this?

The correct way is to use the second constructor of the class, [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29). This constructor was introduced in `Honeycomb`(API level 11) but you could use the `SimpleCursorAdapter` class from the compatibility package to have it on older platform versions(for the flags you could pass 0). The rest of the code is normal `Loader` code that you can see in various samples.

Comment: Ahh! Okay. That makes more sense then. Thank you for clarifying! I was tired when I was working on it last night, and it was driving me crazy. :)